# Jenkins up and running but can't access through browser on port 8080 AWS ubuntu

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have successfully installed Jenkins on AWS server ubuntu V18.04, the service is up and running on the server successfully

```
jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2020-01-20 05:26:40 UTC; 8min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1905 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/jenkins stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1951 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 20 05:26:39 ip-3.106.165.24 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
Jan 20 05:26:39 ip-3.106.165.24 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Jan 20 05:26:39 ip-3.106.165.24 jenkins[1951]: Correct java version found
Jan 20 05:26:39 ip-3.106.165.24 jenkins[1951]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Jan 20 05:26:39 ip-3.106.165.24 su[1997]: Successful su for jenkins by root
Jan 20 05:26:39 ip-3.106.165.24 su[1997]: + ??? root:jenkins
Jan 20 05:26:39 ip-3.106.165.24 su[1997]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Jan 20 05:26:39 ip-3.106.165.24 su[1997]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user jenkins
Jan 20 05:26:40 ip-3.106.165.24 jenkins[1951]:    ...done.
Jan 20 05:26:40 ip-3.106.165.24 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
```

My security groups are setup port 22 for SSH and port 8080 for jenkins and 80 for http

When I attempt to access jenkins through the web browser I get "This site can't be reached" error

Not sure what else I can try, as I have tried every solution under the sun but still the problem persists.

I can SSH into the server and I can access port 80 as I setup nginx on the server successfully.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Regards
Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why port 8080 is not working. I had to change the port to 8081 in the jenkins config file in following location as there are multiple jenkins config file

/etc/default/jenkins

Also changed the security group settings in AWS to match

Works fine now

Further to this is that my ISP is blocking port 8080. I hotspotted my phone and port 8080 was accessible.